# gzip - Extracting without deleting zip file

Tags: windows, command-line, gzip

Right now I am running an extract from a `.gz` file using the Windows `gzip.exe`.

However when I decompress the file, it kills the `.gz` file and leaves me with the extract file.  For example if I run this on the command line:

`gzip.exe -d -f foo.csv.gz`

I get `foo.csv` out of the zip file, but lose the `foo.csv.gz` file.  I have been searching online but couldn't find a flag that says keep the base file or anything.  Is there a flag that I am missing?  Or do I need to extract it and then recompress it in order to archive the file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
gunzip -c foo.csv.gz > foo.csv
```

or (synonymously):

```
gzip -d -c foo.csv.gz > foo.csv
```

Comment: D'oh ... I figured it was something simple.  Thank you very much :)  Is there a solution that I can use *.csv.gz if there are more than one file, or do I need to expand it out and go one by one?

Comment: @judda: On Windows, you'll need to use a FOR loop.